# Error al recuperar registros con Eager Loads Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Me encuentro con los siguientes modelos, donde una ruta(menu) puede tener muchas categorias y las categorias puede contener muchos archivos. Ruta(Menu)->Categorias->Archivos

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class RutaTipo extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'ruta_tipos';
    protected $primarykey = 'ruta_tipo_id';
    protected $fillable   = ['prog_inicio_tipo','menu_tipo','ruta_tipo_archivo','prog_consulta_tipo'];
    protected $hidden     = ['ruta_tipo_id','cod_tipo','created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $dates      = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function categorias(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Categoria','tipo_id','ruta_tipo_id'); 
    }
}
------------------
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Categoria extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'categorias';
  protected $primarykey = 'categoria_id';
  protected $hidden = ['categoria_id','create_at','updated_at'];
  protected $fillable = ['desc_categoria'];
  protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];
  protected $guard = ['categoria_id'];
  public function rutatipo(){
    return $this->belongTo('App\RutaTipo','ruta_tipo_id');
  }
  public function archivos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Archivo','cod_categoria','categoria_id');
  }
}
-------------------
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Archivo extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'archivos';
    protected $primarykey = 'archivo_id';
    protected $fillable   = ['desc_archivo','nombre_fis_archivo','nombre_log_archivo','tamano_archivo','version_archivo','docto_fis_archivo','docto_log_archivo','marca_destacado','nro_descargas'];
    protected $hidden     = ['archivo_id','cod_archivo','cod_categoria','cod_subcategoria','created_at'];
    protected $guard      = ['archivo_id','cod_archivo','cod_categoria','cod_subcategoria'];
    protected $dates      = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    public function categoria(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','categoria_id');
    }
}
```

Con la siguiente estructura Obtendo el menu que quiero desplegar con su relacion de categorias y archivos.Pero cuando intento acceder a los registros

```
@foreach($menu as $file)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->desc_archivo }}</td>
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->nombre_fis_archivo }}</td>
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->nombre_log_archivo}}</td>
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->tamano_archivo}}</td>
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->version_archivo}}</td>
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->docto_fis_archivo}}</td>
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->nro_descargas}}</td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

> $menu->categorias o $menu->categorias->archivos

Envia un error

> "Property [categorias] does not exist on this collection instance."

La funcion en el controlador que envia a la vista la coleccion

```
$menu = RutaTipo::with('categorias.archivos')
            ->where('ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id',$ruta_id)
            ->get();
```

Sigo probando, pero creo que al final es algo que no alcanzo a ver en el modelo. Seria de mucha ayuda alguna orientacion. Adicional a esto, al retornar la variable $menu, me muestra los registros con sus relaciones a categoria y archivos, pero este ultimo solo me dice la cantidad de campos, sin los datos.

[image: Registros relacion eager load]

[image: Registros relacion eager load continuacion]

Comment: No veo que se esté realizando eager loading en ninguna parte (salvo en el título de la pregunta), y ¿en qué contexto estás llamando $menu->categorias?

Comment: Añadi el contexto en la vista, segun lo que entendi de la documentacion, la mencion a eager loading la genero al utilizar el metodo with de las dos tablas anidadas categorias con archivos. Me entrega las categorias al realizar la consulta en la vista de la forma  $menu->categorias, pero no pasa a la de archivos. Tengo solo un par de semanas en este framework y un año programando, espero entiendas que hay cosas "básicas" que se me escapan.

Comment: Me gustaría ver lo que contiene `$menu` con la consulta que muestras.

Comment: Editado con la relacion de la consulta (imagenes)

Comment: Gracias, ¿en qué línea exactamente aparece el error?

Comment: En la vista en el foreach al intentar acceder a los archivos de la relacion como
  @foreach($menu as $file)
              <td>{{$file->categorias->archivos->desc_archivo }}</td>
, con el siguiente error "Property [archivos] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: ¿Todas las categorías tienen archivos relacionados?

Comment: Todos los archivos al ser ingresados, estan relacionados siempre a una categoria, asi como cada categoria esta relacionada siempre con una ruta. Pero, una categoria puede no tener archivo ingresado. Si a eso te refieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando no tienes archivos en alguna categoría, aparece el error que mencionas:

> Property [archivos] does not exist on this collection instance

Esto lo puedes solucionar con el helper optional() de Laravel, el cual arroja null en caso que la propiedad no exista, en vez de arrojar un error, y no necesitas realizar un montón de comprobaciones, solo es una línea:

```
optional($file->categorias->archivos)->desc_archivo
```

Más información en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-optional

Comment: Que curioso. $menu = RutaTipo::with('categorias.archivos')->where('ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id',$ruta_id)->get(); Sigue enviando el mismo error con optional($menu->categorias), pero si cambio get por first, puedo acceder a las categorias, pero me da ese mismo error al acceder a los archivos "$menu->categorias->archivos... Creo ya es algo vicioso. Gracias por tu tiempo y dedicacion,  probare con un metodo SQL.

Comment: Es probable que haya algún error en las relaciones, te puedo garantizar que Laravel y Eloquent funcionan muy bien con lo que intentas hacer, lo he comprobado en muchos proyectos que he realizado. No es necesario SQL en este caso.